# Configuring which Redis adapter to use in Symfony Cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, redis, symfony4

I want to make use of `Predis\Client` instead of `\Redis` for all the Redis connections.

The Symfony docs [on cache adapters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html#available-options) describe that you can give additional options to the `createConnection` method. 
However, this is all autowired in the service container. The only thing I'm declaring is that I want to use Redis for caching:

```
framework:
  cache:
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: '%redis_dsn%'
```

Is there any way I can configure the default options for the RedisAdapter? Or is there another way that I can set Symfony always to use `Predis\Client` for Redis?

Configuring the DSN with `?class=\Predis\Client` works, is this the optimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with adding additional options to the DSN. Being able to configure your provider with just a string is why it exists. However you can define a custom provider service and use whatever configuration you'd like.

From https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#custom-provider-options:

```yml
# config/packages/cache.yaml
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            cache.my_redis:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.my_custom_redis_provider

services:
    app.my_custom_redis_provider:
        class: \Redis
        factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
        arguments:
            - 'redis://localhost'
            - { retry_interval: 2, timeout: 10 }
```

In your case you'd change the class to Client\Predis and change the applicable settings.

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @Will how to configure it for multiples nodes (using a redis cluster for example) ?